# google sheets importhtml used to work, now not working

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I was getting data from the following url https://movelearnplay.edmonton.ca/COE/public/booking/checkavailabilitylocations/f3354137-bdae-4dcd-9683-e471107dbb6b?CheckAvailability=True&StartDate=2022-02-03&FinishDate=2022-02-22&Quantity=1&TimeRangeStart=120&TimeRangeEnd=960&Page=2#results
with =IMPORTHTML("https://movelearnplay.edmonton.ca/COE/public/booking/checkavailabilitylocations/f3354137-bdae-4dcd-9683-e471107dbb6b?CheckAvailability=True&StartDate=2022-02-03&FinishDate=2022-02-22&Quantity=1&TimeRangeStart=120&TimeRangeEnd=960&Page=2#results","table",1) , but suddenly it stopped working today. Can anyone tell me why and what I can do?

Comment: Which informations do you want to retrieve?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Change to number#2 to table

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://movelearnplay.edmonton.ca/COE/public/booking/checkavailabilitylocations/f3354137-bdae-4dcd-9683-e471107dbb6b?CheckAvailability=True&StartDate=2022-02-03&FinishDate=2022-02-22&Quantity=1&TimeRangeStart=120&TimeRangeEnd=960&Page=2#results","table",2)
```

Comment: Thank you, that was a simple and quick solution